# SELECT que traga produtos ativos em uma empresa e que não estejam ativos em todas as outras

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho uma tabela que mostra os produtos que estão Ativos (A) ou Inativos (I) em 16 filiais. Ou seja, tem 16 linhas para cada produto.

Eu quero selecionar todos os produtos que estão Ativos (A) na empresa 16 e ao mesmo tempo devem estar Inativos (I) em todas as outras empresas.

Como posso montar um `SELECT` que me traga estas informações?

Comment: Os ativos que deseja são somente os da empresa de código 16? E que simultaneamente se estiver ativo (nesta empresa 16) esteja inativo pelo menos em qualquer outra?

Comment: Quero buscar os produtos que estão Ativos somente na 16 e simultaneamente inativos em todas as outras

Comment: coloque a estrutura da tabelas na pergunta, ou algum código de exemplo isso facilita o entendimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela_Produtos p INNER JOIN Tabela_Filiais f ON f.id = p.filial_id
WHERE p.filial_id = 16 AND p.status LIKE 'Ativo' AND p.id NOT IN (
      SELECT p2.id FROM Tabela_Produtos p2 
      INNER JOIN Tabela_Filiais f2 ON f2.id = p2.filial_id
      WHERE p2.filial_id != 16 AND p2.status LIKE 'Inativo')
```

Considerando que os dados estão todos em uma tabela **`MRL_PRODUTOEMPRESA`** sua consulta ficará:

```
SELECT * FROM MRL_PRODUTOEMPRESA 
         WHERE (EMPRESA = 16 AND STATUS LIKE 'A')
         OR (EMPRESA != 16 AND STATUS LIKE 'I');
```

A consulta fica mais simples que a primeira, mas tome cuidado com a modelagem do seu banco, pois colocar tudo em uma mesma tabela não é considerado uma boa prática para bancos de dados relacionais e não aconselho, principalmente se for utilizado para projetos profissionais.

---

Não havia me atentado para o detalhe inativos em **TODAS** as outras empresas. Veja se resolve:

```
SELECT * FROM MRL_PRODUTOEMPRESA WHERE EMPRESA = 16 AND STATUS LIKE 'A' AND PRODUTO IN
     (SELECT PRODUTO FROM MRL_PRODUTOEMPRESA WHERE EMPRESA != 16 
        AND STATUS LIKE 'I' HAVING COUNT(PRODUTO) >= 
             (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(PRODUTO)-1 FROM MRL_PRODUTOEMPRESA GROUP BY PRODUTO) 
     GROUP BY PRODUTO)
```

- A  consulta acima busca todos os PRODUTOS da EMPRESA 16 com STATUS Ativo
- Que não estão na lista de EMPRESAS diferentes da 16 com STATUS Inativo
- Que contém o total de PRODUTOS cadastrados menos 1 (referente ao único PRODUTO Ativo)

Comment: Ai que ta, é uma tabela só que tenho essa informação. O nome dela é MRL_PRODUTOEMPRESA.

Nesta tabela tenho uma coluna com nome PRODUTO outra com nome EMPRESA e uma coluna com nome STATUS (além de muitas outras) 

Quero trazer todos os produtos que na empresa 16 estão com status = A (ativo)
Mas que simultaneamente estão com status = I (Inativo) em todas as outras.

Comment: @CelioSartori segue nova resposta no complemento... Abraço!

Comment: Estamos quase lá hehe...

Neste ultima select que você me passou acredito que ele vai trazer todos os produto onde a EMPRESA é diferente de 16 e o STATUS é 'i'

OR (EMPRESA != 16 AND STATUS LIKE 'I');

Neste caso o vai consultar na tabela e se a empresa for diferente de 16 e o status estiver inativo vai me trazer. Até ai esta super correto!

Mas preciso de um detalhe a mais que é ...
TODAS as empresas precisam estar inativas
Somente na 16 ativo. Por exemplo

Produto = 10
Empresas = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 
Status = I (Inativo)

Empresa = 16
Status = A

Comment: @CelioSartori Não havia me atentado para o detalhe inativos em TODAS as outras empresas. Coloquei uma nova consulta, verifique se atende o seu problema.

Comment: Perfeito!

Trouxe exatamente os produtos que eu queria.
Muito obrigado parceiro!

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite

Tente algo assim:

```
IB OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMP_01') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #TEMP_01

SELECT A.PRODUTO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.SITUACAO = 'A' 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END
       ) AS OCORRENCIA_ATIVA
  INTO #TEMP_01
  FROM TB_PRODUTOS A
 WHERE A.LOJA <> 16


SELECT A.*
  FROM TB_PRODUTOS A
  JOIN #TEMP_01    B ON B.PRODUTO = A.PRODUTO
 WHERE A.LOJA = 16
   AND A.SITUACAO         = 'A'
   AND B.OCORRENCIA_ATIVA = 0
```